# How do use Custom ListView in this Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

I'm new to Android development.
Recently i make an app and i don't know how to use custom listview in my activity. im stuck   in this line

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,totalCalculation);
```

when i replace   `R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, to my R.layout.listView,` this app crush so what i do now ?

so I'm stuck in this stage. 
hope you will guy's help me

> this is my MainActivity where i want to use Listview

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

public class CalculationHistoryListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Remove the below line after defining your own ad unit ID.
    //private static final String TOAST_TEXT = "Test ads are being shown. "
      //      + "To show live ads, replace the ad unit ID in res/values/strings.xml with your own ad unit ID.";

    Save saveData;
    ListView listView;
    ArrayList<com.jungleofmagic.chabiri.ListView> arrayList;
    BaseAdapter baseAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculation_history_list);


        // Load an ad into the AdMob banner view.
        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .setRequestAgent("android_studio:ad_template").build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Toasts the test ad message on the screen. Remove this after defining your own ad unit ID.
       // Toast.makeText(this, TOAST_TEXT, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        saveData = new Save(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this);

    }



    public void run(View view){
        //cursor type database
        Cursor database = saveData.display();
        if (database.getCount()==0){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Data Found",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        database.moveToFirst();
        //save string like a array
        final String[] totalCalculation = new String[database.getCount()];
        int n = 0;
        do {
            totalCalculation[n] = database.getString(0).toString();
            n = n+1;

        }while (database.moveToNext());


        ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,totalCalculation);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_calculation_history_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

> and this is my own ListView xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:text="Total"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/total_money"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:text="00:00AM dd:MM:yyyy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:fontFamily="serif"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

> and this is my own listview java file

```
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by AIB Nihan on 11/1/2016.
 */

public class ListView {
    public ListView(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    Date date;
}
```

> this is crush log

```
11-02 16:44:04.006 3983-3983/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.jungleofmagic.chabiri, PID: 3983
                                                 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
                                                     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
                                                     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2091)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                     at android.widget.ScrollView.onLayout(ScrollView.java:1468)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14871)
                                                     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1751)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1007)
                                                     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5677)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                    at and
```

so guy's please tell me how to i use my own listview in my First Activity

Comment: where you stuck ? and what you problem ?. tell clearly

Comment: Thanks for your comment actually im stuck   in this line    
  ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,totalCalculation);

when is replace   R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, to my R.layout.listView, this app crush so what i do now ?

Comment: what is the crash log

Comment: please check my question my.

Comment: Make your own custom list adapter and pass R.layout.listView (i.e. custom list item view) to that adapter.

Comment: Pass your textview id from your custom layout file in Arrayadapter constructor like this and let me know if it is working or not..
new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,R.id.your_textview_id,totalCalculation);

Comment: @Bhavnik Thank you men thank you so much :D it's work now you are great men you are great :D

Comment: @Akram:- I am happy that it solved your problem... Happy coding man...

Answer (score 1):

Pass your textview id from your custom layout file in Arrayadapter constructor like this and let me know if it is working or not..

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(CalculationHistoryListActivity.this,R.l‌​ayout.support_simple‌​_spinner_dropdown_it‌​em, R.id.your_textvie‌​w_id, totalCalculatio‌​n);
```

Comment: It's Work :) Thanks men